# 2d DFT of an image and then its inverse

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, dft

I am computing 2D-DFT using following formula:
img1 = Wm @ img @ Wn     ,size of image is M*N, here, img is my image,@ denotes matrix multiplication. Wm is M*M matrix given by,
 Wm(m,k) = ((1/M)^0.5)exp((-j*2*pi*k*m)/M)and Wn is N*N matrix given by
Wn(n,l)=((1/N)^0.5)exp((-j*2*pi*l*n)/N)
where M*N is size of the image
but computing inverse is not resulting in original image.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2
path='E:\\python programs\\peppers.pgm'

#load image into img
img=cv2.imread(path,0)

height,width=img.shape
img=img.astype(np.complex64)

#img1 will contain dft of image
img1=np.zeros((height,width),dtype=np.complex64)
img=img.astype(np.complex64)

#performing centering of image
for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            img[y,x]=img[y,x]*pow(1,x+y)

#obtaining twiddle matrix Wm                
tmp=1/(pow(height,0.5))
Wm=np.zeros((height,height),dtype=np.complex64)
for x in range(height):
   for y in range(height):
       Wm[y,x]=tmp*math.exp((-1*6.28*x*y)/height)

##obtaining twiddle matrix Wn        
tmp1=1/(pow(width,0.5))
Wn=np.zeros((width,width),dtype=np.complex64)
for x in range(width):
   for y in range(width):
        Wn[y,x]=tmp1*math.exp((-1*6.28*x*y)/width)

#computing dft
img1=Wm@img@Wn        

#img2 will contain inverse dft                      
img2=np.zeros((height,width),dtype=np.complex64)
```

I have computed idft by replacing Wm and Wn by their complex conjugate in the formula of dft
    img2=np.conj(Wm) @ img1 @ np.conj(Wn)

```
#performing decentering
for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            img2[j,i]=img2[j,i]*pow(1,i+j)

img2=img2.astype(np.uint8)

print(img2)
cv2.imshow('image',img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)&0xFF
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: 6.28? There is no way that is precise enough. Please use `math.pi`...

Comment: Also, that centering method works only for even-sized arrays. Do you get the right results without the centering?

Comment: One more thing: note that the * next to a matrix typically indicates conjugate transpose.

Comment: I tried without centering and decentering .But output is not correct.I also used math.pi @CrisLuengo

Comment: You’ve changed your question, and are no longer showing the code for the inverse. But you were using `np.conj(Wm)`, which is the complex conjugate, but you need the conjugate transpose, according to the reference you linked. The * is conjugate transpose, not just conjugate.